# How to display products without selling them (or using the typical ecommerce modules)?

Tags: 7

I am working on a project with drupal 7. My drupal experience is limited and Im a bit stuck on how to achieve a good structure.

The site will have products like wine, sherries and spirits. Each of these product types will have subcategories. (example: like red / white wine) Within these subcategories there will be certain brands of wines.

Since the website is focussing only on displaying the products and not selling them, I really do not want to use any ecommerce software, or modules.

Preferably I would like the products to be a content type. There is a little catch to it. All categories, so in the examples above; wines, sherries, spirits BUT ALSO red / white wines should have a description and a image.

Can anyone shed some light on how to create this in drupal 7. I have searched a lot but I'm not sure what the right approach would be. Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I would use taxonomies for categorizing your products.
Here is a [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/774892) that explains more about taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this without using "commerce" modules are taxonomy and vocabularies, using the [Entity Reference Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

A  simple workflow to achieve this would be:

1).Create the corresponding **Vocabulary** with the desired **term structure** from admin/structure/taxonomy/add, for example:

- Wine
- - Red
- - - Brand #1  etc.

2). Create The **Content Type** with the desired Fields

3). In the content type, add an "Entity Reference" Field, assigning it to the **vocabulary**

4). Create your products (Add content)

5). Create **Views** to customize the display of each page depending on the term level (using filters)